Updating Components
I have a modal that changes out Select components from Mantine UI based on user input.



When I click on Select by County I want the MultiSelect to be disabled by default. (Done)
When the user selects a state I'm filtering through a json file of county data and saving that to state using useState.
Once a state has been selected I want the County MultiSelect to no longer be disabled and to update the selection options.
This all works fine if I define the County MultiSelect in the return of the function.
I originally had the Select and MultiSelect defined inside of the component but outside of the return as follows:
const hucSelect = (
    <Select
        label='Watershed Layers'
        placeholder='Select One'
        data={[
            { value: 'huc2', label: 'HUC2' },
            { value: 'huc4', label: 'HUC4' },
            { value: 'huc6', label: 'HUC6' },
            { value: 'huc8', label: 'HUC8' },
        ]}
    />
);

const countySelect = (
    <MultiSelect
        label='County'
        disabled={countiesDisabled}
        data={filteredCounties}
    />
);

const stateSelect = (
    <Select
        label='States'
        placeholder='Select One'
        data={states}
        onChange={(_value) => filterCounties(_value)}
    />
);

Then I was using a switch statement inside of useEffect to update another state variable based on which radio button (aoiChoice) the user selected as follows:
useEffect(() => {
    switch (aoiChoice) {
        case 'state':
            setSelectOptions([stateSelect]);
            break;
        case 'county':
            const options = [stateSelect, countySelect];
            setSelectOptions(options);
            break;
        default:
            setSelectOptions([hucSelect]);
            break;
    }
}, [aoiChoice]);

Then in the return statement where the JSX is, I was inserting selectOptions to the DOM as follows:
{selectOptions.map((option) => {
    return option;
})}

Doing this however would not update the disabled attribute or the select options. How do I go about updating those components that are defined outside of the return statement?
